# REACT.js and render but using innerHTML of element rendering into?

Tags: reactjs

I have a need and I can't seem to overcome it.

Because my page uses both templating rendering AND react... I have this div that has an id, lets say 'foo'.

Now, I'd like to take the contents of "foo", THEN render my component with the contents of foo. My React component needs to have a certain look, but the page template has another.... does that make sense?

ie.

page renders with something like:

```
<div id="foo">
   <ul>
     <li>Item One</li>
     <li>Item two</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

then in my jsx file, I have:

```
var fooElem = document.getElementById('foo');
var contents = fooElem && fooElem.innerHTML || '';

if(fooElem) {
    React.render(
      <MyCOMPONENT data={contents} />,
       fooElem
    );
}
```

I figure it would be an easy thing to just get the innerHTML of the div and then render a component in it with 'new' component content surrounding the 'innerhtml' that I grabbed. As you can see, I take a prop of "data" and I use that within my component to spit it out again, but in a different format. etc... that "foo" div is handed back by the backend, so I can't alter it other than "trying to get the innerHTML, manipulate it, and render a component into that space..".

Any help would be appreciated.

I get errors that the element has been modified and such.. and seems to just go in some kind of loop.

Comment: If you have access to the HTML and the innerHTML, why not just recode it all in React? What you are trying to do seems like a very bad anti-pattern.

Comment: why would it be an anti-pattern? It just seems like a normal operation that React should be able to handle. I have access to it, but I do not have access on what determines the content.

Comment: Sorry - I thought you meant that you had full access to actually creating what is inside `foo`. When you render the React component, do you want it alongside `foo`, or should it replace `foo`?

Comment: well, I want to basically take the contents and insert it into my component, then have my component render to div foo. basically, grab the contents of foo -- put that content into my component then render my component to elem foo. So, the user would see the "same thing" just but would be styled differently.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react');

var myComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      content: ''
    };
  },
  // Learn more about React lifecycle methods: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html
  componentWillMount: function() {
    // Get the content of foo
    var content = document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML;

    // Remove the old templated foo from the page
    // This assumes foo is a direct child of document.body
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('foo'));

    this.setState({
      content: content
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    <div id={'foo'}>
      {this.state.content}
    </div>
  }
});

// This assumes you want to render your component directly into document.body
React.render(myComponent, document.body);
```

This will:

1. Read the contents of `foo` into the React component's state.
2. Remove the `foo` element from the page.
3. Render the new React component (with the content of `foo`) into the page.

Comment: Is there not a more simple way to assign the innerHtml of an object with a state prop?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper not really. Ideally a React app should never manually modify the DOM - everything should be done via `props` and `state`